# Sqlite3: Inserting single variable using?

Tags: sqlite

I'm currently trying to insert a group of strings using the ? character and the data is not appearing in the database. I have a feeling that it has something to do with only using a single ? instead of multiple.

-I've tried using a tuple as the second parameter of the execute method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def insertBrokerTable(brokerName):

    conn = sqlite3.connect(brokerData)
    c = conn.cursor()

    inputData = [brokerName]

    c.execute("insert or ignore into Broker (BrokerName) values (?)", inputData)
    conn.commit
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert multiple _values_ or are you trying to do multiple _inserts_?

Comment: Multiple inserts. I'm parsing a csv file and need to insert every element (single string) into the database. I'm using this function within a for loop if that helps.

Comment: It didn't fix the problem, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Wow ... I figured it out. Literally just for got the () after commit ... spent hours looking for a solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was going to say that I see nothing wrong with your code.